# Can we do like this using PHP SESSION array?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Hi can we create two dimensional array using php session. If possible how to unset values randomly.

Comment: You can, and it behaves as a normal array does. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your question!

Comment: What do you mean, unset values randomly? From the array? Only the deepest level, or can whole branches be unset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, PHP does not implement multi-dimensional arrays. However an element of an array can be an array itself. And any PHP data item can be stored in the session (however resources become meaningless outisde the thread they were initialized in, and objects require class definitions to be referenced from the session).

e.g.

```
<?php

$two_d=array(
    array(1,2,3),
    array(4,5,6),
    array(7,8,9),
    array('#','.','=')
    );
$two_d[3][2]='*'; // was '='
```

> how to unset values randomly

This would be an oxymoron in a 2-dimensional array. But is perfectly valid in the context of an array of arrays:

```
unset($two_d[1]); // removed the whole second row from the above
unset($two_d[0][1]); // $two_d[0] is now array(1,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['whateverValue'] = Array(
  1 => Array (
    'a','b','c','d'
  ),
  2 => Array (
    'q','w','e','r','t'
  )
);
```

Voila, a two-dimensional array, in a session.

The session variables are in no way special while the script is executing. Their only "magic" is  that they are unserialized at session_start() and serialized at session_close()

Comment: Use either `unset($_SESSION['whateverValue'])` or `session_destory()`

Comment: @Petah: Yes, I know how to unset session variables, I'm not sure what "unset randomly" is supposed to mean.

Comment: That's not a 2-dimensional array. It's an array of arrays.

Comment: @symcbean: Indeed it is an array of arrays; it works like a multidimensional array though: `$_SESSION['whateverValue'][1][0] == 'a'` . What other implementation do you suggest, in PHP?

Comment: @Piskvor: it's not impossible to create a genuine N-D array using PHP - but you'd need to wrap all access in PHP code. The differences are important (it makes no sense to multiply and array of arrays by some other entity, but matrix manipulation requires N-D arrays.

Comment: @symcbean: Aha, it makes sense now. Thanks for the explanation.